# How to map an arraylist of hashmap to anothoer hashmap arraylist

Tags: java, spring-boot, arraylist, hashmap

I have a `Switch` that contains 13 `case`, each case executes a different sql request. I got the result in an `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`. This result is supposed to be displayed with angular , for now i'm using this `this.respTest = JSON.stringify(response);` so it displays a list of "key":"value" .

My problem is since each request gets me different database fields and values ,so I want to merge some fields .
I created this class :

```
public class DataCollect {

private String type ; 
private String entity ; 
private String modPar ;
private String dateModif ; 
private String numVersion ;

public DataCollect(String type, String entity, String modPar, String dateModif, String numVersion) {

    this.type = type;
    this.entity = entity;
    this.modPar = modPar;
    this.dateModif = dateModif;
    this.numVersion = numVersion;
}

public DataCollect() {

}
public String getType() {
    return type;
}
public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
public String getEntity() {
    return entity;
}
public void setEntity(String entity) {
    this.entity = entity;
}
public String getModPar() {
    return modPar;
}
public void setModPar(String modPar) {
    this.modPar = modPar;
}
public String getDateModif() {
    return dateModif;
}
public void setDateModif(String dateModif) {
    this.dateModif = dateModif;
}
public String getNumVersion() {
    return numVersion;
}
public void setNumVersion(String numVersion) {
    this.numVersion = numVersion;
} }
```

In this class I'm supposed to affect the fields' names to the variables that I created and as a return an arraylist of hashmap with the data I extracted from the data base.
I mean I used to return for example "field-name":"value" , I want to return "type":"value","entity":"value" ..etc

I'm using springboot for the backend and angular 5 for the front.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is your problem to convert the result of the SQL query [resultSet] to a List<DataCollect> ...??

Comment: @ShubhamMaheshwari no , it's more complicated , i already got the result in an arraylist , yet i wan't to make a mare specific / personalized list , in which instead of displaying the result as "field-name":"value" , i display it as one of the variables that i already created  like "type":"value"

Answer (score 0):

What you essentially want is a way to map keys in [each of] your hashmap to the corresponding member variable in the "DataCollect" POJO.

If there is a one to one mapping between the key present and corresponding member variable, you can expose a public constructor in "DataCollect" that takes in the hash map and constructs the corresponding object.

```
public DataCollect(Map<String, String> result) {
    this.type = result.get("type");
    this.entity = result.get("db_entity_key");
    ...
}
```

If there is no one on one mapping, you'd have to create a factory class, which takes your Map as an input and some context, and returns you the constructed DataCollect object.

Once you have the constructor or the factory class, you only need to iterate over your results list and do the needful to convert each Map into the DataCollect object.

Your controller should automatically serialise the DataCollect objects to corresponding JSON, or you can even use Jackson's ObjectMapper to achieve the same.